# Exception not caught when using PowerShell command line but caught as expected when using PowerShell ISE

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am running PowerShell 2.0.

I have a PowerShell script that adds a record to the database and returns the ID of the record added.
The record ID is returned as a property called `new_deal_id` within a DataRow object (called `ResultSet`).

If there is a problem on the database end it is possible that the `new_deal_id` property does not get set, or doesn't exist at all.

To counter this scenario I wrapped the reading of the property in a try/catch block as shown here.

```
try {
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
    $ResultSet = Read-DatabaseData -OdbcCommand $OdbcCommand -SqlQuery $Sql
    $NewDealID = $ResultSet.new_deal_id
}
catch {
    throw
}
finally {
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
}
```

If I run the script using the PowerShell ISE or PowerGui the exception shown below gets caught when the property doesn't exist

```
Property 'new_deal_id' cannot be found on this object. Make sure that it exists.
At line:1 char:12
+ $ResultSet. <<<< newdeal
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (.:OperatorToken) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict
```

However if I run the script from the PowerShell command line the exception does not get caught and the script continues as if no error occurred.

Why is the PowerShell command line not catching the exception when the property doesn't exist?

Comment: that is strange indeed. ise is running with a different profile, maybe there is something in there that explains the behaviour (couldnt reproduce in v4 though). Probably your ise profile has strict mode enabled. you can use `set-strictmode` to enable it in your console. If that doesnt yield the results you want you could workaround it by checking the existance of the property with `get-member`

Comment: have you tried adding `-ErrorAction Stop` to your statement? This should throw the error to your catch clause. I'm not really sure though why it is behaving differently for you.

Comment: @Paul. I should have mentioned in the original question description that strict mode is set at the beginning of the script using `Set-StrictMode -Version latest`. Also I don't know if it's relevant but this code is contained within a Module.

Comment: @silent. Setting the $ErrorActionPreference variable to "Stop" is the equivalent of using the `-ErrorAction Stop` command in a CmdLet. So if any error occurs the code should stop and jump to the catch block.

Comment: @Paul. Hi Paul. Using the get-member CmdLet didn't help but your mention of strict more got me thinking. When I debug through the script on the command line and enable strict-mode just before testing for the presence of the property I get the expected exception. So it looks like the strict mode that I set in the main script is not passed on to the function within the module. I'm not sure why that is. Either way, it has solved my problem. Do you want to add your comment as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: hi gerard, i have added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because you dont have strict mode enabled in the console you are running your script in. (Powershell and ISE use different profiles)

To enable strict mode use the `Set-Strictmode` cmdlet.

Example:

```
Set-StrictMode -Version latest
```

Comment: The strict mode is set in the main script but is not passed to the function within a separate module. As suggested by Paul The full solution was to set the strict mode again in the function prior to testing for the presence of the property.