# "Manually" thrown exception caught in PowerShell ISE but not on command line

Tags: python, powershell, exception

I have a Powershell script that runs some Python scripts and is supposed to catch any exceptions thrown. The desired behaviour is that the console window is not closed after an exception, so that the user can see the output and only closes after hitting enter.

This is the function that executes the Python scripts:

```bsh
# functions for exception handling
function safe-run {
    # exceptions thrown by python are not terminal in powershell
    # therefore, we throw error here, if exit code was 1
    Param([string]$command)
    invoke-expression "$command $args"
    if ($lastexitcode -eq 1) {
        throw "Python process finished with exit code 1"
    }
}
```

This is the block in the main script that is supposed to catch the exception thrown by the function above and pause the script:

```bsh
# run the application
Try {
    safe-run $Executable $Arguments
} Catch {
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    Write-Host "$ApplicationName threw a terminal exception. Error message: $ErrorMessage"
    Break
} Finally {
    conda deactivate
    # Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
    Pause
}
```

If I run this with some example code in Powershell ISE it works. For example using `safe-run "python" "-c 'import sys; print(sys.versio)'"` produces:

```
python : Traceback (most recent call last):
At line:1 char:1
+ python -c 'import sys; print(sys.versio)'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Traceback (most recent call last)::String) [], RemoteExcep 
   tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'versio'
 threw a terminal exception. Error message: Process finished with exit code 1
Press Enter to continue...:
```

However, running this from the command line, the Python exception is raised and the `Finally` block is not executed. Any idea why? I Have tried the suggested solutions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849716/exception-not-caught-when-using-powershell-command-line-but-caught-as-expected-w), but neither adding `-ErrorAction Stop` nor `Set-StrictMode -Version latest` worked.

Comment: So the catch block gets executed in both console and ISE, but not finally? I tried your example and it worked as it should. Can you include the output when running in console in your question? Also, replace the commands in the catch/finally blocks with write-host, for debugging.

Comment: The catch block is also not executed, on the command line it just raises the error and outputs the error message. In fact, I just ran the simple example I gave on the command line and the exceptions is caught as expected, but somehow when I use the actual Python script it doesn't work, it just raises the exception thrown by `safe-run`.

Comment: add a try/catch in your safe-run function. That will capture any python error and forwards it to your main script

Comment: I found the issue.. the script was executed by another function before without a catch block where it threw the exception. The functions above indeed work as expected..